# How can I combine this two htaccess rules?

Tags: .htaccess

I have two conditions for the pages **/portfolio** and **/portfolio/**

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ index.php?p=portfolio&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^portfolio/$ index.php?p=portfolio&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Is there a possibility to combine this conditions?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^portfolio/?$ index.php?p=portfolio&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

the `?` says "exactly 0 or 1 '/'"